# How to run node crypto module with browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify

I need to use [crypto.pbkdf2](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback) on my browser.

I use browserify to create my javascript file. The asynchronous PBKDF2 function freeze my browser entirely when iterations are larger than 1000.

[image: pbkdf2 freeze]

[RequireBin example](http://requirebin.com/?gist=be479128d481c1ff4d5d)

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');
var iterations = 10;
// var iterations = 8192; // uncomment to freeze the browser
crypto.pbkdf2('password', 'salt', iterations, 32, 'sha256', function (error, key) {
    console.log(key.toString('hex'));
});
```

**How to run node crypto module with browserify ?**

Edit:

here the code created by browserify to declare pbkdf2

```js
exports.pbkdf2 = pbkdf2
function pbkdf2 (password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest, callback) {
  if (typeof digest === 'function') {
    callback = digest
    digest = undefined
  }

  if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
    throw new Error('No callback provided to pbkdf2')
  }

  var result = pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest)
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback(undefined, result)
  })
}
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Dalton yes see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix my problem I use the pbkdf2 module from npm: https://github.com/crypto-browserify/pbkdf2

```
npm install --save pbkdf2
```

This package implement a [browser version](https://github.com/crypto-browserify/pbkdf2/blob/master/browser.js) and proxy the [node version](https://github.com/crypto-browserify/pbkdf2/blob/master/index.js#L7)

Depending on the target you want to reach (browser or node) your bundler (browserify or webpack) will load the appropriate version.

```
var pbkdf2 = require('pbkdf2');
pbkdf2.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest, function(error, key) {
...
});
```